# Canceling in fractions sometimes gives a wrong result

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

When the same factor appears in the numerator and denominator, it can be canceled out: 
$$\frac{4a}{4a} = 1$$ 
However, in this more complicated fraction this does not work: 
$$\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a} \neq c-b^2$$
Why is that?

Comment: Please provide more information.  What quadrilateral equation and what is $k$?

Comment: @kier, I think you may have mean "quadratic equation" ...You should also say what's $\,k\,$ and write down the whole question. As it is now it makes no sense.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, you're right. it's quadratic equation. a(x-h)^2 +k = ax^2 + bx + c right? and for you to solve for k if the given is the general equation ax^2 + bx + c, you should coming up with the equation k =4ac−b^2/4a and to get h= -b/2a.

Comment: Nice @kier, now please try to make *clear* what your question is: is it what condition(s) exist on $\,a,b,c\,$ so that you have the equality yo wrote?

Comment: @DonAntonio hmm, I tried the same given but when i am getting for the k and using the 2 equation to get k, sometimes i came up with different answer. SOMETIMES ONLY, IS IT REALLY DEPENDS on the given?

Comment: Please post your original problem.

Comment: Once again, @kier : what **exactly** are the given data and **what** exactly is the question?!

Comment: Ok. for example 2x^2 + 5x + 6, in getting k using 4ac-b^2/4a, i came up with the answer 23/8. then i used the c-b^2 and came up with different answer, -19.

Comment: @kier, you continue to make no sense: what is that misterious $\,k\,$ in your last equation?! And you get an "answer"...to **what**? What is the question?

Comment: @Don: it's about fractions. http://i.imgur.com/43fpaXT.jpg

Comment: Ok @kier, it seems to be your question about cancelling has already been addressed. Yet that misterious $\;k\;$  is, apparently, going to remain a mistery...oh,well.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the core of your issue is "cancellation." You can only "cancel" common ***factors*** of the numerator and denominator. Otherwise, you could pull nonsense like $$\frac32=\frac{2+1}2=1$$ by exactly the same reasoning as in your post (after all, isn't $\frac22=1$?)

When we do "cancellation" with fractions, here's what's really going on behind the scenes. If $x,y,z$ are numbers with $y,z\ne0,$ then $$\frac{xz}{yz}=\frac{x\cdot z}{y\cdot z}=\frac xy\cdot\frac zz=\frac xy\cdot 1=\frac xy,$$ or for a direct numerical example, $$\frac{6}{15}=\frac{2\cdot 3}{5\cdot 3}=\frac25\cdot\frac33=\frac25\cdot 1=\frac25.$$ We don't usually show all of these steps, but it's good to keep in mind that we're doing this. Let's look at another example: $$\frac{xz+z}{z}=\frac{(x+1)\cdot z}{1\cdot z}=\frac{x+1}1\cdot\frac zz=(x+1)\cdot 1=x+1.$$ It's tempting to just try to "cancel" by crossing out the $z$ on top and bottom (to get $xz$), but you *must* keep in mind what we're actually doing, because with that kind of reasoning you get (for example) that $$\frac{6+2}{2}``="6,$$ when what we *should* be getting is $$\frac{6+2}{2}=\frac{(3+1)\cdot 2}{1\cdot 2}=\frac{3+1}1\cdot\frac22=(3+1)\cdot 1=3+1=4$$ (which could be done more simply, but I wanted to illustrate the process again).

---

Regarding the application (to the quadratic equation) in question, we can still "cancel", but we have to be a bit careful, and introduce the factor $4a$ in a clever way, using the fact that $a\ne 0$: $$\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}=\frac{4ac-1\cdot b^2}{4a}=\cfrac{4ac-\frac{4a}{4a}b^2}{4a}=\cfrac{\left(c-\frac1{4a}b^2\right)\cdot 4a}{4a}=\left(c-\frac1{4a}b^2\right)=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}.$$

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a} = \frac{4ac}{4a}-\frac{b^2}{4a} = c-\frac{b^2}{4a} \neq c-b^2 \textrm{ if } a \neq \frac14$$

Comment: Ok but why can't we just cancel out the 4a/4a since trigo. students always taught of that. Sorry but I just need more info. I'm just a confused trigo student. :)

Comment: @kier The numerator is the sum two terms: $4ac$ and $-b^2$. The $4a$ in the denominator divides both terms. However, it only cancels the $4a$ in the first, because there is no $4a$ in the second! Dividing by $4a$ is the same as multiplying by $\frac{1}{4a}$, so we're really using the distributive property here:
$$\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a} = \frac{1}{4a}\left(4ac-b^2\right) = \frac{1}{4a}\cdot 4ac - \frac{1}{4a}\cdot b^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

Your question is "Why can't I cancel the $4a$ terms in the top and bottom of a fraction to get
$$
\frac{\color{red}{4a}c-b^2}{\color{red}{4a}}=c-b^2
$$
The problem with this is that on the left side, the term $4ac-b^2$ must be divided *entirely* by $4a$. You've only divided part of the top by $4a$. In other words, to get each term on the top to be a multiple of $4a$ we could multiply the $b^2$ term by $4a/4a$ to get
$$
\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}=\frac{4ac-\frac{4a}{4a}\cdot b^2}{4a}=\frac{4a\cdot c-4a\cdot \frac{b^2}{4a}}{4a}=\frac{4a(c-\frac{b^2}{4a})}{4a}
$$
and now you can indeed do the cancellation of the $4a$ terms to conclude
$$
\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}
$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to know when

$$a(x-h)^2+k=ax^2+bx+c\iff ax^2-2ahx+ah^2+k=ax^2+bx+c\iff$$

$$\begin{cases}-2ah=b\iff a=-\frac b{2h}\\{}\\ah^2+k=c\iff a=\frac{c-k}{h^2}\end{cases}$$

Comparing the above we get

$$-\frac b{2h}=\frac{c-k}{h^2}\iff-bh=2c-2k$$

Without any more information I don't think one can say much more...